# installing gtk+ on mac osx 10.11.4 El-Capitan

Tags: python, macos, gtk

I have a macbook pro with `osx 10.11.4 El-Capitan`. I use `zsh`, which I wonder could be causing problems? I've been tinkering with python for the last year on a wide variety of small projects with no problems, so my environment is pretty stable. I needed `gtk`, so...

I started with this

`git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtk+`

I am following the instructions here to build the `gtk+` distribution:

https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show//Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building?action=show&redirect=GTK%2B%2FOSX%2FBuilding

Things seemed to be progressing until I ran this step :

```
jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap
```

and get the following error :

> checking for python module libxml2... not found
>   configure: error: Python module libxml2 is needed to run this package
>   *** Error during phase configure of itstool: ########## Error running ./configure --prefix /Users/Dad/gtk/inst    *** [7/12]

So I tried :

```
brew install libxml2
```

gives me :

> OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
>   parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include
```

Any ideas on how to proceed ? The problem seems like libxml2 is installed but can't be found by jhbuild - so I expect this to be a relatively common problem, easy to fix, but I'm stuck? I'm not sure where to set these environment variables. I set them from the command line and reran but same result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you seem to be using homebrew, why not install gtk using `brew`?

Comment: I had a feeling I'd be asked that - I had problems which is outside the scope of this question - tried to fix some of those and looked for another way, which was what I listed above.

Comment: You could try using jhbuild to set up a private build environment. The OS X instructions are a bit of a mess, though... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue as well and am not sure what causes it. We had a discussion on the gtk-osx-devel mailing list some time ago: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-osx-devel-list/2015-April/msg00000.html

Summary: For some reason the libxml package isn't installing the Python module in the right place. To work around it, when itstool fails, choose the "start a shell" option and run the following commands:

```
cd ../libxml/python
make install
exit
```

Then try to continue with the build.

Comment: This is exactly the actions I took, and as you describe it, it solves the problem.

I looked at the thread you pointed to in your reply, but I did not see if a fix was being worked on.

Have you had any luck finding the root cause of the issue?

Comment: No, I haven't. It's definitely something with libxml's build system, but I don't know any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and tried ptomato's answer and it didn't work for me. But I found the right .py file:

```
find ~ -iname "libxml2.py"
~/gtk/source/libxml2-2.9.8/python/libxml2.py
~/gtk/inst/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libxml2.py
```

And copied it and the libxml2mod library it needs, over to the python2.7 site packages:

```
cp ~/gtk/source/libxml2-2.9.8/python/libxml2.py ~/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
cp ~/.cache/jhbuild/build/libxml2-2.9.8/python/.libs/libxml* ~/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I don't know (or care) why the libxml2/python makefile can't install it into the right place. However I'm leaving this here so I don't forget and run into the same problem next time.